# java code to generate automatic id like "d001" for doctor, "p001" for patient which should be stored in the database

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

i am creating a website called hospitalService and i have a database for this with tables doctor_details and patient_details now i want a java code to generate automatic id which looks like d001 for doctor and p001 for patient please help me to write this code thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you do this in Java and not let the database generate ids for you?

Comment: Have you tried something to do this? At least have you tried googling about your doubt? Nobody will spoon feed you with answers here. Please do your homework.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "give me teh codes" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sequence generator to generate your unique Id. For each category you said above(eg: doctor, patient) you can create different sequence. The method and syntax to create a sequence depends on the DB that you are using.

Furthermore, if you are using JPA or Hibernate  or any other persistence API, then most probably you will be enable to generate such sequence with the help of API only.

For ex: In JPA you can use the following annotation to create a sequence(Note that there are other ways to do the same but this is just for your reference).

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="my_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq",sequenceName="MY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Always depend on the respective DB provided sequence for populating primary id of each record in DB.

1. Please check the respective DB documentation for usage of Sequence type DB objects.
2. For oracle refer here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF54244
3. While applying DB insert take next value of sequence and apply your custom desired string e.g. for doctor : "d"+ next value of doctor sequence or for patient: "p" + next value of patient sequence.

Comment: Learn to google :) ... http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Sequence/Usesequenceininsertcommand.htm

Comment: +1, a very helpful advice indeed